# Dropout rate in bottle neck layers

Tags: neural-network, dropout

It is common to use a dropout rate of `0.5` as a default which I also use in my fully-connected network. This advise follows the recommendations from the original Dropout paper (Hinton at al).

My network consists of fully-connected layers of size

`[1000, 500, 100, 10, 100, 500, 1000, 20]`.

I do not apply dropout to the last layer. But I do apply it to the bottle neck layer of size 10. This does not seem reasonable given that `dropout = 0.5`. I guess to much information gets lost. Is there a rule of thumb how to treat bottle neck layers when using dropout? Is it better to increase the size of the bottle neck or decrease dropout rate?

Answer (score 2):

Drop out layer is added to  prevent over-fitting(relgularization) in neural Network.

Firstly  Drop out rate adds noise  in output values of layer to break  happenstance patterns that cause overfitting .

here droput rate of 0.5 means 50% of values shall be droped out, which is a high noise ratio and a definite No for bottle neck layer.

I would recommend you train your bottle neck layer without dropout first and then compare its results with increasing dropout.

choose the model that best validates your test Data.